# How to make route to save data in users table in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am working with Laravel 5.7 and do not go Auth command and make Login and Registration. but I have UserController and save data in users table as following.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
        ]);

        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => str_random(40)
        ]);

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

        return $user;
    }
```

now how can I make Route in web.php file to save above data.

Comment: What you have created in routes file for this?

Comment: try with seeder class and write above code to seeder and run seeder for add to users table.

Answer (score 0):

Make `create` method public and add `fillable` property in your models and try to make route like this:

```
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@create');
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

add the following to routes:
`Route::post('url', 'ControllerName@MethodName');`

which will be like below in your case:

`Route::post('register', 'UserController@create');`

Answer (score 0):

1. You must change your method to `public` instead of `protected`.
2. In your `web.php` routes file set the route as `post`.

   Example: `Route::post('route_name', 'MethodController@method_name');`
3. On your method create you can use `Request $request` to get the data.

Example:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $name = $request->data[0];
    $email = $request->data[1];
    $address = $request->data[2];

    (rest of your code)
  }
```